# EF not executing where clause at DB level

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4

Disclaimer: I changed the names of the service/entities/etc... to generic stuff for SO in Notepad. If you see an inconsistency with regards to class names, ignore them please, as it isn't the problem.

I'm working on a WCF service for a client and am having some issues with expressions I'm serializing.  I am currently using [Serialize.Linq](https://github.com/esskar/Serialize.Linq) to deal with the expression serialization.  On top of that, I'm using my DataContract classes to create the expression on the client side, and converting it to an expression using my Entity class.

Assume these two classes:

1. MyEntity (part of the DataContract namespace in the project)
2. MyEntity (part of the Entities namespace in the project)

Both have identical properties, and I use AutoMapper to convert the entities I get via EF to my DataContract object, then send that object back to the client.

To deal with the expression conversion, I'm using an ExpressionVisitor class:

```
class MyExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public ParameterExpression ParameterExpression { get; private set; }

    public MyExpressionVisitor(ParameterExpression newParameterExp)
    {
        ParameterExpression = newParameterExp;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return ParameterExpression;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Member.DeclaringType == typeof(DataContracts.MyEntity))
        {
            return Expression
                .MakeMemberAccess(this.Visit(node.Expression), typeof(Entities.MyEntity).GetMember(node.Member.Name).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

This is how I'm calling my service:

```
Expression<Func<DataContracts.MyEntity, bool>> expression =
    fl.SomeNameField1 == "John Doe" || fl.SomeNameField2 == "John Doe";
var entities = manager.MyService.GetFilteredEntities(expression.ToExpressionNode());
```

This is my current service implementation (partial, omitting return lines, etc...) for `GetFilteredEntities`:

```
// Using Serialize.Linq for send expressions over WCF.
// query is an ExpressionNode from the Serialize.Linq library.
// This DOES NOT execute the where clause on the database.
var expression = query.ToExpression<Func<DataContracts.MyEntity, bool>>();
var visitor = new MyExpressionVisitor(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Entities.MyEntity), expression.Parameters[0].Name));
var entityExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Entities.MyEntity, bool>>(visitor.Visit(expression.Body), visitor.ParameterExpression);
var func = entityExpression.Compile();
var entities = this.Entities.MyEntities.Where(func);
```

All of this code *works*, but the `Where` isn't applied at the database level, it's applied against the in memory set of *every* row from my table.  This takes a long time, as the table has 150k+ rows.

If I hard code the where I'm wanting in the service, it applies the where clause at the database level:

```
// This DOES execute the where clause on the database.
var temp1 = this.Entities.MyEntities.Where(fl => fl.SomeNameField1 == "John Doe" || fl.SomeNameField2 == "John Doe");

// This DOES execute the where clause on the database.
Func<Entities.MyEntity, bool> func2 = fl => fl.SomeNameField1 == "John Doe" || fl.SomeNameField2 == "John Doe";
var temp2 = this.Entities.MyEntities.Where(func2);
```

I know I could just write a bunch of different service opperations that would allow the user to filter by passing in names, ids, whatever, but this table has a ridiculous amount of columns (200+), and I have ZERO input on said database.  It's a lot easier for other developers who may be using the client I'm writing to be able to create an expression using whatever data & columns they feel like, so I'd *love* to get this applying the where at the db level.

I'm almost certain I've included everything in this post that is relevant.  I used SQL Server Profiler to check the queries EF was running, that's how I know which ones used the where.  Please ask for more information where/if needed.

Thanks!

/walloftext

Comment: Have you looked at the Dynamic Linq library? http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: @ken, briefly (same blog post), but I didn't want to have to use strings to create the query, as it's easier and strongly typed going the route I did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the problem is with this line:

```
var func = entityExpression.Compile();
```

Since you are calling `Where` with a compiled delegate function, you are not calling the overload of Where that actually gets sent to the DB.

You need to pass an expression object to `Where` (i.e. call [one of these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.where.aspx))

Comment: Ugh, that was it.  I haven't dealt with Expression Trees much like this before, and was following the example for `Serialize.Linq`.  Seriously, thank you a ton!  Verified removing that and just calling `.Where(entityExpression)`.  Will mark this as the answer as soon as SO lets me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should be compiling your expression before you use it in your `Where` clause. Doing so will invoke the extension method provided in `System.Core` by the `System.Linq` namespace. You want the method overload that takes an object of type `Expression`.

In other words, try removing this line:

```
var func = entityExpression.Compile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `LinqKit` to create compound queries? It provides, with  `PredicateBuilder`, an easy way to work with Expressions.

Take a look at [this address](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), the source code is quite straight-forward, it did miracles in my case.

Comment: I love `PredicateBuilder`, but it wouldn't help here as far as I know, mainly because I'm having to serialize over WCF.